# fancybox directive not grouping images

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, fancybox

I have created directive for fancy box. it opens image in fancy box not grouping images . i checked other solution here in [Fancybox directive in ng-repeat is not grouping images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23688042/fancybox-directive-in-ng-repeat-is-not-grouping-images)  but they won't solve my problem.

**HTML:**

```
<a fancybox class="fancybox" rel="group" data-thumbnail="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_s.jpg" href="{[{i.location}]}" title="{[{i.name}]}" width="460" height="298">
## Image ###<img src="{[{i.location}]}" alt="" width="460" height="298" />
</a>
```

**JS fancy Box Directive ::**

```
 App.directive('fancybox',function($compile, $timeout){
        return {
            link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
                alert('i am called');

                   element.fancybox({
                    openEffect : 'none',
                    closeEffect : 'none',
                    padding : 40,
                    margin : [20, 60, 20, 60] ,// Increase left/right margin
                    helpers: {
                    thumbs: {
                        width  : 40,
                        height : 40,
                        source  : function(current) {
                            return $(current.element).data('thumbnail');
                            }
                        }
                   },
                });
            }
         };
    });
```

Comment: Did you ever get this solved? I, too, cannot group images anyhow... May be post your answer and close this issue as solved? :)

Comment: @ilter i did it with angular bootstrap carousel

Comment: thanks for the answer. But as you know, carousel and fancybox are two different concepts used to solve different kind of problems. Of course it's good if it solved your problem, but what I mean is, they're not really interchangable in terms of usage.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't achieve it with fancybox .anyways i switched to using bootstrap carousel , bootstrap is more easy to use ,

```
    <div ng-controller="CarouselDemoCtrl">
  <div style="height: 305px">
    <carousel interval="myInterval">
      <slide ng-repeat="slide in slides" active="slide.active">
        <img ng-src="{{slide.image}}" style="margin:auto;">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h4>Slide {{$index}}</h4>
          <p>{{slide.text}}</p>
        </div>
      </slide>
    </carousel>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" ng-click="addSlide()">Add Slide</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      Interval, in milliseconds: <input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="myInterval">
      <br />Enter a negative number or 0 to stop the interval.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Bootstrap Carousel With Angular](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

we can do lot of customization in bootstrap provided Carousel .